# z/VSE sample jcl to print sequential file to spool

Tags: mainframe, jcl, vsam

I am trying to print the contents of a ca-datacom sequential file by using IDCAMS/REPRO, but was getting the below error.

IDC3300I  ERROR OPENING TEST001
IDC3318I ** INVALID DATA SET SPECIFICATION

IDC0005I NUMBER OF RECORDS PROCESSED WAS 0

IDC3003I FUNCTION TERMINATED. CONDITION CODE IS 12

Below is z/vse job, could any one help

```
* $$ JOB JNM=TESTING,USER='TEST ',CLASS=‎0,PRI=3,DISP=D       
* $$ PRT CLASS=L                                               
* $$ LST CLASS=L                                               
//   JOB       TEST 
* $$ SLI J.UCATT‎1                                              
//   DLBL      TEST001,'TEST.DAT',1,SD               
//   EXTENT    SYS‎067,TEST02,,,1,70                            
// EXEC IDCAMS,SIZE=AUTO                                       
 PRINT INFILE (TEST001)  CHAR                                  
/*                                                             
/&                                                             
* $$ EOJ
```

Can any one please help, Also can any one provide me a sample job to copy sequential file to VSAM file by IDCAMS/REPRO in z/vse with file parameters. i know how IDCAMS work in Z/OS but not sure hoe to do it in z/vse

Comment: Here's the manual: ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/s390/zos/vse/pdf3/zvse31/doc/iesvoe10.pdf

Comment: From *Messages and Codes Vol 2*: "IDC3318I ** INVALID DATA SET SPECIFICATION Explanation: The ENVIRONMENT parameter or the DLBL or TLBL statement has been incorrectly specified. The information is incorrect, or required parameters are missing. System Action: Processing of the command is terminated. Programmer Response: Check the  ENVIRONMENT parameter to ensure that all required parameters are specified. Also check the DLBL or TLBL job control statement to ensure
that it is correctly specified. Correct any error and rerun the command." We can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you are "trying to print the contents of a ca-datacom sequential file", but CA Datacom does not reside in sequential files. If you are trying to print data from CA Datacom tables then that can be achieved using either CA DataQuery or the DBSQLPR program in CA Datacom/SQL. If your site does not have either of those optional components, then you could use the CA Datacom Reporting Facility (also known as DataReporter or DRREPORT) which is delivered as part of the CA Datacom/DB base products in both z/VSE and z/OS.